# Query using greater than with a timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing a trivial query where I'm looking for records with a `created_at` later than the given timezone, for example: `2015-11-30T11:16:15.039Z`

By doing

```
User.where(["created_at > ?", '2015-11-30T11:16:15.039Z'])
```

I was expected not to received the record that has that time, although it returns it. It feels like it is behaving as if my query was `created >=`.

Another thing that comes to my mind is that the `created_at` is not a timezone in the database, it is stored in this format:

```
         created_at
----------------------------
 2014-06-25 04:51:35.689021
```

And that might be the issue, but I'm not sure at this point how to solve it.

Any recommendations are really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get records by created at with time zone like:-

```
User.where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
or 
User.where("created_at > ?", Time.zone.utc_to_local(DateTime.parse("2015-11-30T11:16:15.039Z"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Timezones are a constant issue.

**TL;DR**

```
User.where(['created_at > ?', Time.zone.parse('2015-11-30T11:16:15.039Z')])
```

---

Within your rails application, It would be ideal to define what timezone it is running in within `config/application.rb`

```
module MyAwesomeApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
    ...
  end
end
```

You can find out a list of valid time-zones by running the following rake command:-

```
rake time:zones:all
```

Now, when performing a query you could do something like this.

```
User.where(['created_at > ?', Time.zone.parse('2015-11-30T11:16:15.039Z')])
```

In this case, we are taking the given UTC ISO8601 format and passing it through the `Time#parser` applying the application time zone.

This should ensure the queried time is in a format which Active Record will like, and also include full time zone information in relation to the application.